# Iteration over dictionary

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have setup a Flask app trying to fetch data from the [classic Drinks API](https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=vodka).

Here is a shortened sample of the output given by this API

```
{
  "drinks": [
    {
      "idDrink": "13196",
      "strDrink": "Long vodka",
      "strCategory": "Ordinary Drink",
      "strGlass": "Highball glass",
      "strInstructions": "Shake a tall glass with ice cubes and Angostura, coating the inside of the glass. Por the vodka onto this, add 1 slice of lime and squeeze juice out of remainder, mix with tonic, stir and voila you have a Long Vodka",
      "strIngredient1": "Vodka",
      "strIngredient2": "Lime",
      "strIngredient3": "Angostura bitters",
      "strIngredient4": "Tonic water",
      "strIngredient5": "Ice",
      "strIngredient6": null,
      "strIngredient7": null,
      "strIngredient8": null,
      "strIngredient9": null,
      "strIngredient10": null,
      "strIngredient11": null,
      "strIngredient12": null,
      "strIngredient13": null,
      "strIngredient14": null,
      "strIngredient15": null
    },
    {
      "idDrink": "16967",
      "strDrink": "Vodka Fizz",
      "strCategory": "Other/Unknown",
      "strGlass": "White wine glass",
      "strInstructions": "Blend all ingredients, save nutmeg. Pour into large white wine glass and sprinkle nutmeg on top.",
      "strIngredient1": "Vodka",
      "strIngredient2": "Half-and-half",
      "strIngredient3": "Limeade",
      "strIngredient4": "Ice",
      "strIngredient5": "Nutmeg",
      "strIngredient6": null,
      "strIngredient7": null,
      "strIngredient8": null,
      "strIngredient9": null,
      "strIngredient10": null,
      "strIngredient11": null,
      "strIngredient12": null,
      "strIngredient13": null,
      "strIngredient14": null,
      "strIngredient15": null
    }
  ]
}
```

How do you iterate over a value that has the same name but ends with something else?
For example, they have: `strIngredient1-15`.

Not sure, but maybe regex is better or `match`/`endswith` and then use `{{ variable }}` to present it.

I understand it can be done in many ways but I can't figure out how to proceed, I just need some push in the right direction.

I was trying to loop over it but I am getting the error

> `NoneType` is not iterable

On the line

```
{% if 'strIngredient' in inner_dict[ingr] == null %}
```

My full code is

```
<tbody>
    {% for outer_dict in data_output %}
        {% for inner_dict in data_output[outer_dict] %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ inner_dict['idDrink'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ inner_dict['strDrink'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ inner_dict['strCategory'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ inner_dict['strGlass'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ inner_dict['strInstructions'] }}</td>
            {% for ingr in inner_dict %}
                {% if 'strIngredient' in inner_dict[ingr] == null %}
            <td>{{ inner_dict[ingr] }}</td>
    </tr>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: @PatrickYoder yeah, sorry, was a bit unclear. I wonder how do you "iterate over a value that has the same name but ends with something else".

The error I get about "NoneType" was:

    {% if 'strIngredient' in inner_dict[ingr] == null %}
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have to compare the attributes of the dictionary to `strIngredient`, the idea should be to use the [`for` construction to loop over a dictionary](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#for):

> As variables in templates retain their object properties, it is possible to iterate over containers like dict:
>
> ```
> <dl>
> {% for key, value in my_dict.items() %}
>    <dt>{{ key|e }}</dt>
>    <dd>{{ value|e }}</dd>
> {% endfor %}
> </dl>
> ```

With this, you have both the key and value of the dictionary, and it is way easier to compare your string to the key given by the `for` itself.

Mind that:

- there is also a [`for ... if ...`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#loop-filtering) construct in Jinja that can simplify your actual use case
- you can use the [`startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) method of a Python string in your particular use case: `drink_attribute.startswith('strIngredient')`
- you also have to check if the ingredient is not `None` since you have some `null` values for ingredients in the input JSON
- it is always useful to give meaningful name in your code (e.g. `drinks` — plural since it is a list of drink — instead of `data_output`, `drink` instead of `outer_dict`, ...).

All this together gives this loop for the ingredients:

```
{%- for drink_attribute, ingredient in drink.items() 
    if drink_attribute.startswith('strIngredient') and ingredient 
%}
  <td>{{ ingredient }}</td>
{%- endfor %}
```

And this is the loop to create a table with all the drinks:

```
<table>
  <tbodby>
    {% for drink in drinks %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ drink.idDrink }}</td>
      <td>{{ drink.strDrink }}</td>
      <td>{{ drink.strCategory }}</td>
      <td>{{ drink.strGlass }}</td>
      <td>{{ drink.strInstructions }}</td>
      
      {%- for drink_attribute, ingredient in drink.items() 
            if drink_attribute.startswith('strIngredient') and ingredient 
      %}
        <td>{{ ingredient }}</td>
      {%- endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  <tbody>
<table>
```

This will render in (some spacing and style added for readability):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbodby>
    
    <tr>
      <td>13196</td>
      <td>Long vodka</td>
      <td>Ordinary Drink</td>
      <td>Highball glass</td>
      <td>
          Shake a tall glass with ice cubes and Angostura, 
          coating the inside of the glass. 
          Por the vodka onto this, 
          add 1 slice of lime and squeeze juice out of remainder,
          mix with tonic, 
          stir and voila you have a Long Vodka
      </td>
        <td>Angostura bitters</td>
        <td>Vodka</td>
        <td>Tonic water</td>
        <td>Ice</td>
        <td>Lime</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>16967</td>
      <td>Vodka Fizz</td>
      <td>Other/Unknown</td>
      <td>White wine glass</td>
      <td>
          Blend all ingredients, save nutmeg. 
          Pour into large white wine glass 
          and sprinkle nutmeg on top.
      </td>
        <td>Limeade</td>
        <td>Vodka</td>
        <td>Ice</td>
        <td>Nutmeg</td>
        <td>Half-and-half</td>
    </tr>
    
  <tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me in the right direction and solved the question. Still learning about key, value and wrapping my head around it. About the naming.. I agree, but for now when learning I use datatypes naming just to memorize it all :)